# iPhone:Query regarding iPhone app Submission

Tags: iphone

I have a question here regarding iPhone app submission. I have a free application submitted in AppStore already. I made the same application with additional features to submit as priced version. I am going to use the same provisional profile as i have created PP as not wild card one. Do i need to follow filling up the app submission form etc again as same i did for free app? (Or) is there any other short thing that i need to do for my case?

thanks for your suggestions.

-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to treat it as a second app, and fill out everything, otherwise this app will look like an update to the other and will replace it.